# TypeError: encoding without a string argument

Tags: python

I looked up lots of similar question, but sadly none of them are close to mine.

I have a simple script that checks balance from exchange. It is a part of an unofficial API wrapper written in python and my understanding is it stuck somewhere between python 2 and python 3. I fixed errors one by one, but I'm completely stuck with this one. Here is the code:

```
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
import json
import time
import hmac,hashlib


class Poloniex():
    def __init__(self, APIKey, Secret):
        self.APIKey = APIKey
        self.Secret = Secret

    def api_query(self, command, req={}):
        self.req = bytes(req, 'utf-8')
        req['command'] = command
        req['nonce'] = int(time.time()*1000)
        post_data = urllib.parse.quote(req)
        my_key = self.Secret
        my_key_bytes = bytes(my_key, 'utf-8')
        post_data_bytes = bytes(post_data, 'utf-8')

        sign = hmac.new(my_key_bytes, post_data_bytes, hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
        headers = {
        'Sign': sign,
        'Key': my_key_bytes,
        #'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }

        ret = urllib.request.urlopen(
            urllib.parse.quote('https://poloniex.com/tradingApi', safe=':/'), post_data_bytes,
                headers)
        jsonRet = json.loads(ret.read())
        return self.post_process(jsonRet)

    def returnBalances(self):
        return self.api_query('returnBalances')



inst = Poloniex("AAA-BBB", "123abcdef")

balance = inst.returnBalances()
print(balance)
```

Looks like I have a problem with syntax, but even after RTM I can't figure this out. It throws me:

```
TypeError: encoding without a string argument
```

and before that I had:

```
TypeError: quote_from_bytes() expected bytes
```

which was 'fixed' by

```
self.req = bytes(req, 'utf-8')
```

Can anybody please point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

**UPD**

sorry, forgot the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 43, in <module>
    balance = inst.returnBalances()
  File "script.py", line 37, in returnBalances
    return self.api_query('returnBalances')
  File "script.py", line 18, in api_query
    post_data = urllib.parse.quote(req)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/parse.py", line 775, in quote
    return quote_from_bytes(string, safe)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/parse.py", line 800, in quote_from_bytes
    raise TypeError("quote_from_bytes() expected bytes")
TypeError: quote_from_bytes() expected bytes
```

Comment: Which of the above lines of code throws the TypeError?

Comment: oops, update the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, `req` is a dictionary, but you're attempting to convert it to `bytes` here: `self.req = bytes(req, 'utf-8')`, which doesn't make sense since only strings can be converted this way.

The second error is caused by the fact that `urllib.parse.quote` works only with strings and `bytes`, but you're passing it a dictionary.

Comment: and without it I get "quote_from_bytes() expected bytes" :(

Comment: @Colton, you're constantly passing dictionaries instead of `bytes`

Comment: isn't that must be covered by post_data = urllib.parse.quote(req) and post_data_bytes = bytes(post_data, 'utf-8') ?

Comment: @Colton, I've explained it in my answer: `req` is a _dictionary_, you can't pass a dictionary to `quote`.

Comment: I guess I'll just have to pump up my skills in Python and rewrite the whole thing the way I see it, because the original script is just a mess and I have no enthusiasm cleaning it up. Thanks!